# Calculating convergence order for Newtons method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I am trying to teach myself numerical analysis and I am trying to find out how you determine the order of convergence for newtons method. On the wiki there are multiple formulas for newton methods convergence chapter, some with a q value and some without and I am incredibly confused.

I have the nonlinear equation: $f(x) = -cos + x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 = 0$
I have the values from the iterations with initial guess -2 and calculated the error between iterations as $e_n = |x^* - x_n|$ but I'm not sure what to do after this to determine order of convergence. Would appreciate any insight.

Newton iteration values:

Iteration 1: $x1=−2.000153634$

Iteration 2: $x2=−2.000152282$

Iteration 3: $x3=−2.000152293$

Iteration 4: $x4=−2.000152293$

Error between iterations: $e_n = |x^* - x_n|$:
e0= |-2.000152293-(-2)|=0.000152293

$e1=|-2.000152293-(-2.000153634)|=0.000001341$

$e2=|-2.000152293-(-2.000152282)|=0.000000011$

$e3=| -2.000152293-(-2.000152293)|=0$

$e4=| -2.000152293-(-2.000152293)|=0$

Comment: Start farther away from the root, for instance $x_0=-1.5$. Or use a multi-precision library to get errors for the later iterations. This is in general a good idea, as the Newton method converges so fast, if it converges at all, that you get only a few iterations in the quadratic-convergence mode, about 3 steps usually.